# Оптимизация при работе с БД

Tags: java, mysql

Всем привет! Есть таблица в БД с несколькими столбцами, среди которых ид, наименование, юзер, оценка и средняя оценка.
Сейчас при выставлении **пользователем** новой оценки **наименованию** я перебираю все ранее поставленные **наименованию** **оценки** (тяну из базы) и на основе этого выставляю **среднюю оценку наименованию**
Возможно кто-то подскажет, как можно оптимизировать этот процесс? Потому как при большом количестве оценок это явно будет не оптимально. Возможно хранить еще отдельно последнюю среднюю оценку и количество оценок на данный момент, но как с этим совладать при добавлении новых оценок я в толк взять не могу. Буду признателен за подсказки и наводки.
Пишу на Java использую MySQL.

Comment: а зачем её вообще хранить, если можно подсчитать на основе всех оценок?

Comment: @Igor, представьте, что у нас 100 000 оценок и тут еще одну добавили. Все 100 000 вытягивать будем? Автор разумно и пишет: "при большом количестве оценок это явно будет не оптимально"

Comment: @Сергей смешная шутка, 100к это много? да и что, что мы добавили, ты и так будешь тянуть, если конечно ты не выводишь только среднюю. А если много оценок, а значит что много пользователей, то что сумма и счётчик в другой таблице будет лежать, а это больше запросов, учитывая что бд слабое место, то тут можно поспорить, что будет оптимальнее при высокой нагрузке

Comment: я в поиске более оптимального решения)

Comment: @Igor, 1) именно поэтому я и написал в ответе про натурный эксперимент, и что это может быть не нужно в каком-то случае. 2) Автор пишет только про среднюю, так что не обязательно все 100k "и так будем тянуть". Но вопрос задан правильно, проверять надо такие вещи.

Comment: @valerjan оптимальное решение обычно в том случае, если это место по результатам тестов, является слабым местом. Преждевременная оптимизация может только хуже сделать, вплоть до ужаного и не читаемого кода, который никто не поймёт. Насчёт вычисления среднего, я думаю агрегационные функции в бд неплохо справятся.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы уже отчасти ответили.
Я советую следующий алгоритм на базе вашей идеи:

1. Хранить отдельно общую сумму оценок (числитель средней оценки) и  количество оценок на данный момент (знаменатель средней оценки). Хранить среднюю оценку для целей пересчета смысла не вижу.
2. При добавлении новой оценки соответственно увеличивать хранимые числитель (+новая оценка) и знаменатель (+1), рассчитывать новую оценку на их основе.

Но советую проверить натурным экспериментом, насколько это выгоднее, чем заново все пересчитывать каждый раз. Наверное, да - оптимальнее, но если и при простом пересчете нагрузка на систему будет минимальна, то надо задуматься, нужно ли это небольшое усложнение.

Примечание на всякий случай: я не работаю с БД, изучаю mySQL для ML. Но вряд ли от этого ответ неверным станет:-)

Comment: вчитывался в Ваш совет!) надо попробовать, спасибо!)